# Recent activity page missing/hidden filter buttons (IE7) on new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As per the title, when you click the envelope icon and open the recent activity page the filter buttons (today, yesterday, week, etc) are hidden - except for the right edge of "Last Month", which poking out on the side a bit (and works when clicked).

I'm on IE7, and this does not happen on any other SE site (that I am aware of).

## Screenshot:

[image: Recent activity: where have my filter buttons gone?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have now been fixed, at least it's fixed for me on the same system that orginally showed the error.